# Java Object.wait(long, long) Implementation different from Documentation

Tags: java, jvm, wait

The method `Object#wait(long, long)` in `java.lang.Object` states in it's documentation that

> This method is similar to the `wait` method of one
>   argument, but it allows finer control over the amount of time to
>   wait for a notification before giving up. The amount of real time,
>   measured in nanoseconds, is given by:
>   `1000000*timeout+nanos`

This in itself makes sense, but the implementation does not reflect the documentation:

```
public final void wait(long timeout, int nanos) throws InterruptedException
{
    // ... Some range checks

    if (nanos >= 500000 || (nanos != 0 && timeout == 0))
    {
        timeout++;
    }

    wait(timeout);
}
```

As you can see, instead of actually using the `nanos` parameter, it simply rounds it to milliseconds and adds it to the `timeout` parameter, which it then uses to call the less precise `wait(long)` method.

---

Why is the implementation of `wait(long, long)` so different from it's documentation? Is it an intrinsic method that is treated specially by the JVM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that this is just the default implementation and the JVM intrinsifies it in a platform-specific manner when generating optimized code through its JIT compilers.

Similar things happen with - for example - Math.{min,max,abs} methods, they are implemented in java but get replaced by optimized assembly by the compilers.

As @Nitram mentioned, windows only provides [millisecond OS-level thread scheduling/waiting](https://blogs.oracle.com/dholmes/entry/inside_the_hotspot_vm_clocks). And even measuring (not even waiting) at nanosecond precision is [fairly problematic](http://shipilev.net/blog/2014/nanotrusting-nanotime/) under windows.
I.e. the better implementations cannot be the default implementation because they are only available on some platforms.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know even the high precision timers in Windows give you a resolution down to a millisecond ([MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn265247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). And as Java internally has to use some timer implementation to handle the waiting operation, I guess that is the limiting factor.

Comment: Then what is the point of having the `wait(long, long)` method anyways? To me, it would have made more sense to either remove it or, more reasonably, make it `native` and hide the actual implementation.

Comment: I think timing this more precise can be done. I remember reading *somewhere* that with Linux you get resolutions below a millisecond, but I don't know how reliable timings at this level are on consumer computer. So either this `wait(long, long)` function is there for historical reasons because *someone* considered it a good idea, or there are special implementations of Java that have a differing implementation that provides a better resolution.